# morris.js as angular js directive data 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, morris.js

I am using morris.js charts in my angular js app.
I converted it to directive like that:
**barchart.js:**

```
angular.module('app_name').directive('barchart', function () {
    return {
        // required to make it work as an element
        restrict: 'AEC',
        template: '<div class=chart_div></div>',
        replace: true,
        // observe and manipulate the DOM
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            var data = $scope[attrs.data],
                xkey = $scope[attrs.xkey],
                ykeys = $scope[attrs.ykeys],
                labels = $scope[attrs.labels];

            Morris.Bar({
                element: element,
                data: data,
                xkey: xkey,
                ykeys: ykeys,
                labels: labels,
                hideHover: true,
                grid: false
            });

        }

    };

});
```

then, in my **page.html** I use the directive like that:

```
<section class="graphs" ng-controller="ChartController">
<div class="graphs_box">
    <div class="graphs_box_title">My Orders</div>
    <div class="chart_bg">
        <div barchart xkey="xkey" ykeys="ykeys" labels="labels" data="MyData"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I am adding the data to the chart in '**ChartController**'
like that:

```
        getChartData = function () {
        $scope.xkey = 'X';
        $scope.ykeys = ['Y'];
        $scope.labels = ['Total Tasks', 'Out of Budget Tasks'];
        $scope.PlannedChart = [
          { range: 'A', total_tasks: 20 },
          { range: 'B', total_tasks: 35 },
          { range: 'C', total_tasks: 100 },
          { range: 'D', total_tasks: 50 }
        ];
    };
```

It works. But when I try to add data from DB (json formatted) like that:

```
    getChartData = function () {
        ChartsService.getCharts("orders").success(function (data) {
            $scope.xkey = 'X';
            $scope.ykeys = 'Y';
            $scope.labels = ['Total Tasks', 'Out of Budget Tasks'];
            $scope.OrdersChart = data.Val_Chart;

        });
    };
```

It doesn't work.
The data is fetched from DB - OK (I saw it while debugging).
Also, I noticed when I debugged that the code first goes to barchart.js whith 'undefined' data, and only after that to the service that fetches the data.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because of `getCharts("orders")` working asynchronously here. You'd need to call `setData(data)` on the object, that `Morris.Bar()` returns. See [the Morris.js Documenation](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)

I fixed it, with putting all the attributes for the directive in a single object and using this as link-function:

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {


            var params = $scope[attrs.params];
            angular.extend(params, {element: element});

            var graph = Morris.Line(params);


            var refresh = function(new_params) {
                graph.setData(new_params.data);
            }

            $scope.$watchCollection(attrs.params, refresh);

        }
```

`$scope.$watchCollection(attrs.params,refresh);` observes the params object on the scope and you just give this object a new data-array, after the async loading finished. This updates it.

This is the directive element:

```
<barchart params="sentin_chart"></barchart>
```

And this ist the object in the controller:

```
$scope.sentin_chart = {};
$scope.sentin_chart.data = [];
$scope.sentin_chart.xkey = 'day';
$scope.sentin_chart.ykeys = ['sent_in'];
$scope.sentin_chart.labels = ['Sent in Stories'];
```

As I said you just need to put the new data array into this object to update the graph `$scope.sentin_chart.data = %NEWDATAARRAY%`

I hope this makes any sense for you.